# tsql - Setting sequential values without looping/cursoring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to set a non-unique identifier in a data table. This would be sequential within a group ie. for each group, the ID should start at 1 and rise in incremements of 1 until the last row for that group.

This is illustrated by the table below. "New ID" is the column I need to populate.

```
Unique ID  Group ID  New ID
---------  --------  ------
1          1123      1
2          1123      2
3          1124      1
4          1125      1
5          1125      2
6          1125      3
7          1125      4
```

Is there any way of doing this without looping/cursoring? If looping/cursoring is the only way, what would the most efficient code be?

Thanks

Comment: Why store this New ID? It can be easily computed from the actual data, and if you compute it at the point of usage, it won't be at risk of being wrong. I'd use a `ROW_NUMBER()` solution, as the answers below do, but I'd put it in a view or directly in queries.

Answer (score 6):

One method is to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` in an `UPDATE...FROM` statement with a `subquery` in the `FROM clause`.

```
update MyTable set NewID = B.NewID
from
MyTable as A
inner join (select UniqueID, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GroupID order by UniqueID) as NewID from MyTable) as B on B.UniqueID = A.UniqueID
```

- [MSDN has a good sample to get you started:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)
- You need to utilize a subquery in the FROM clause in order to utilize a windows function (Row_Index())
- Partition By tells the server when to reset the row numbers
- Order By tells the server which way to order the group's NewID's

Comment: Note this won't work in SQL Server prior to the 2005 version.

Comment: You don't need the Join here.

Comment: Martin, I see that you are replacing it with a CTE. Could I say the same about the CTE? I am not clear which is more efficient

Comment: The CTE version will be more efficient as both have to do the row_number stuff but it avoids the join back to the base table. See [execution plans](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/457/executionplans.jpg). BTW in generating these I noticed that in your answer `SET UniqueID = B.UniqueID` should be `SET NewID = B.NewID`

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Damien's point in the comments but you don't need a `JOIN` you can just update the CTE directly.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT [New ID],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group ID] ORDER BY [Unique ID]) AS _NewID
FROM @T       
)
UPDATE cte
SET [New ID] = _NewID
```

[Online Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/108172/)

Comment: +1 I agree. It can also be done without partition in case you are using an old version of ms-sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    UniqueId,
    GroupID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY UniqueId) AS NewIdx
FROM
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will also work, if you are running an old version of mssql

```
--Test table:

DECLARE @t table(Unique_ID int, Group_ID int,   New_ID int)

--Test data:

INSERT @t (unique_id, group_id)
SELECT 1, 1123 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1123 UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1124 UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1125 UNION ALL SELECT 5, 1125 UNION ALL SELECT 6, 1125 UNION ALL SELECT 7, 1125 

--Syntax:

UPDATE t 
SET new_id = 
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM @t 
    WHERE t.unique_id >= unique_id and t.group_id = group_id 
    GROUP BY group_id) 
FROM @t t

--Result:

SELECT * FROM @t 

Unique_ID   Group_ID    New_ID
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1123        1
2           1123        2
3           1124        1
4           1125        1
5           1125        2
6           1125        3
7           1125        4
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to RowNumber() if you're on SS 2000

```
SELECT  UniqueID,
        GroupID,
        (SELECT COUNT(T2.GroupID)
        FROM    myTable T2
        WHERE   GroupID <= T1.GroupID) AS NewID
FROM    myTable T1
```